# Error While executing a SSIS package which contains a script task through SQL Server Agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a `SQL Server 2012` SSIS package with a script task along with other tasks [data flow, execute sql tasks ]. When I manually executed the job its completed successfully.

But when I executed the package through `SQL Job Agent`, it is getting failed with the below error message.

> "Error: 2014-05-13 12:45:14.67
>
> Code: 0x00000001
>
> Source: Script Task
>
> Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> End Error
>
> DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>
> Started:  12:45:10 PM
>
> Finished: 12:45:14 PM
>
> Elapsed:  4.353 seconds"

My `Script Task` is for load data in Text File and add to variable

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("E:\\IEREVISIPDKE\\IELOADING.txt");

        string st = sr.ReadToEnd();
        this.Dts.Variables["IE"].Value = st;

        //MessageBox.Show(st);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does that local path (E:\\IEREVISIPDKE\\IELOADING.txt) exist in the SQL Server that is running the job? Does the SQL Server agent account have access to that path?

Comment: i found that SQL Server Agent doesn't have access to file path...i follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742324/how-do-i-grant-access-to-sql-server-agent-to-be-able-to-write-modify-system-file and now it worked! 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add permission to your `SQL Job Agent Service` account to the specified folder.

My best guess is that when you execute from SSIS, you run as yourself, and you have full access to your folder.

When running `SQL Job Agent`, it uses the service to access your folder, and this user has no access to your specified folder.

Answer (score 0):

try adding C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop folder. It resolved my issue.

Comment: this may resolve the issue, but please elaborate why and how.